# Get IPrincipal from OAuth Bearer Token in OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have successfully added OAuth to my WebAPI 2 project using OWIN. I receive tokens and can use them in the HTTP Header to access resources.

Now I want to use those tokens also on other channels for authentication that are not the standard HTTP requests that the OWIN template is made for. For example, I am using WebSockets where the client has to send the OAuth Bearer Token to authenticate.

On the server side, I receive the token through the WebSocket. **But how can I now put this token into the OWIN pipeline to extract the IPrincipal and ClientIdentifier from it?** In the WebApi 2 template, all this is abstracted for me, so there is nothing I have to do to make it work.

So, basically, **I have the token as a string and want to use OWIN to access the user information encoded in that token.**

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found a part of the solution in this blog post: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/10/31/retrieving-bearer-tokens-from-alternative-locations-in-katanaowin/

So I created my own Provider as follows:

```
public class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        var value = context.Request.Query.Get("access_token");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            context.Token = value;
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Then I needed to add it to my App in Startup.Auth.cs like this:

```
OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
   Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
   AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
   {
       OnCreate = create,
       OnReceive = receive
   },
};

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

With a custom AuthenticationTokenProvider, I can retrieve all other values from the token early in the pipeline:

```
public static Action<AuthenticationTokenCreateContext> create = new Action<AuthenticationTokenCreateContext>(c =>
{
    c.SetToken(c.SerializeTicket());
});

public static Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext> receive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
{
    c.DeserializeTicket(c.Token);
    c.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = c.Ticket.Properties;
});
```

And now, for example in my WebSocket Hander, I can retrieve ClientId and others like this:

```
IOwinContext owinContext = context.GetOwinContext();
if (owinContext.Environment.ContainsKey("Properties"))
{
    AuthenticationProperties properties = owinContext.Environment["Properties"] as AuthenticationProperties;
    string clientId = properties.Dictionary["clientId"];
...
 }
```

Comment: No idea how you figured out this. I can`t find any documentation about it, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

By default, OWIN use ASP.NET machine key data protection to protect the OAuth access token when hosted on IIS. You can use MachineKey class in System.Web.dll to unprotect the tokens.

```
public class MachineKeyProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purpose =
    {
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
        "Access_Token",
        "v1"
    };

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purpose);
    }
}
```

Then, construct a TicketDataFormat to get the AuthenticationTicket object where you can get the ClaimsIdentity and AuthenticationProperties.

```
var access_token="your token here";
var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector());
AuthenticationTicket ticket = secureDataFormat.Unprotect(access_token);
```

To unprotect other OAuth tokens, you just need to change the _purpose content. For detailed information, see OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware class here:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware.cs

```
if (Options.AuthorizationCodeFormat == null)
{
    IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector(
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).FullName,
        "Authentication_Code", "v1");

    Options.AuthorizationCodeFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
}
if (Options.AccessTokenFormat == null)
{
    IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector(
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
        "Access_Token", "v1");
    Options.AccessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
}
if (Options.RefreshTokenFormat == null)
{
    IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector(
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
        "Refresh_Token", "v1");
    Options.RefreshTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
}
```

Comment: so this means you would have to use the same protector on both the webapi and the other app (say some stand-alone signalR console app)?

Comment: And what about self-hoseted owin app where we don't have access to System.Web?

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej Then you have to use the DPAPI DataProtector instead of the MachineKeyDataProtector.

Comment: Yes, exactly like what I explained in the following answer

Answer (score 1):

in addition to **johnny-qian** answer, using this method is better to create DataProtector. **johnny-qian** answer, depends on IIS and fails on self-hosted scenarios.

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
var dataProtector = app.CreateDataProtector(new string[]   {
     typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
     "Access_Token",
     "v1"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your token like, is it an encrypt string or a formatted string, what is it format?

I my code:

```
public static Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext> receive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Token))
        {

            c.DeserializeTicket(c.Token);
            //c.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = c.Ticket.Properties;
        }
});
```

The c.Ticket is always null.