# Web API / OWIN, SignalR & Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr, owin

I am developing a prototype of an AngularJS, Web API, SignalR application as a potential starting point for a new project in VS 2013.

At this stage, I'm pretty much using the canned code that visual studio generates for Individual User Accounts.

There's a line in the StartUp.Auth.cs code that looks like this.

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

With this in place, I can add the [Authorize] attribute to controllers and it works fine.

Incidentally, with angular I was able to add a standard header containing the token in the JavaScript as follows.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'bearer ' + access_token;
```

Then I added SignalR to the project.
It supports it's own version of the [Authorize] attribute but there is no way to pass custom headers when using SignalR.
It's a limitation on the browser side.
The documentation said you could pass the token as part of the query string.
I added that code on the JavaScript side. My SignalR code now included this.
I passed the token as 'bearer_token'.

```
this.connection = $.hubConnection("/TestHub", { useDefaultPath: false, qs: "bearer_token=" + token });
```

So my issue was how to make OWIN recognize the token now it was no longer in the header.
After a number of searches, I ended up adding code that moved the token from the querystring into the header.
For my prototype, I just added a little code above the original line in StartUp.Auth.cs.

So, now it looked like this:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnRequestToken = context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/TestHub"))
            {
                string bearerToken = context.Request.Query.Get("bearer_token");
                if (bearerToken != null)
                {
                    string[] authorization = new string[] { "bearer " + bearerToken };
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(context);
        }
    }
});


// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

The code above is rough but this is a prototype so really I just wanted to see if it worked which it did.

**Finally getting to the question:**
Is this the right pattern for integrating bearer token authorization with SignalR and the OWIN pipeline.
I couldn't seem to find much good information on the right way to do this.

Comment: Is it working right now? This is probably the best attempt I have seen.

Comment: It works fine. Just so little guidance to know how to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: I do something similar but I have wrapped it up in a OWIN middleware module.

Comment: Oddly setting the header did nothing for me... I had to just put the cookie value into the context...  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken))
                        {
                            context.Token = bearerToken;
                        }

Answer (score 19):

I use a class like this:

```
public class OAuthTokenProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    private List<Func<IOwinRequest, string>> _locations;
    private readonly Regex _bearerRegex = new Regex("((B|b)earer\\s)");
    private const string AuthHeader = "Authorization";

    /// <summary>
    /// By Default the Token will be searched for on the "Authorization" header.
    /// <para> pass additional getters that might return a token string</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="locations"></param>
    public OAuthTokenProvider(params Func<IOwinRequest, string>[] locations)
    {
        _locations = locations.ToList();
        //Header is used by default
        _locations.Add(x => x.Headers.Get(AuthHeader));
    }

    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        var getter = _locations.FirstOrDefault(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x(context.Request)));
        if (getter != null)
        {
            var tokenStr = getter(context.Request);
            context.Token = _bearerRegex.Replace(tokenStr, "").Trim();
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Which instead of just passing on the token to the header, parses it and sets it on the context.

Then it could be used in your app configuration like this:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new OAuthTokenProvider(
         req => req.Query.Get("bearer_token"),
         req => req.Query.Get("access_token"),
         req => req.Query.Get("token"),
         req => req.Headers.Get("X-Token"))    
});
```

Then the following styles of requests would have their token read, for use with authentication and/or authorization:

```
GET https://www.myapp.com/authorized/endpoint?bearer_token=123ABC HTTP/1.1
GET https://www.myapp.com/authorized/endpoint?access_token=123ABC HTTP/1.1
GET https://www.myapp.com/authorized/endpoint?token=123ABC HTTP/1.1

GET https://www.myapp.com/authorized/endpoint HTTP/1.1
X-Token: 123ABC

GET https://www.myapp.com/authorized/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Authorization: 123ABC
```

Comment: +1 Could you please show a bit more code, specifically the config/startup code and the client side?

Comment: Does that help? For the js client with signalr I think it's something like:
`jQuery.hubConnection(url,{qs:"access_token="+token})`

Comment: @calebboyd +1 Thanks, exactly what I was after. How exactly are you setting the `X-Token` or `Authorization` header(s)?

Comment: In the response handler of the token endpoint, set a default header... The specifics I guess depend on your xhr abstraction...

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This how I solved it

```
var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
var token = authData.token;
 $.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: "Bearer " + token };
```

No change on the server side code

Hope it helps someone

Comment: doesn't this conflict with the fact that on Winsock the javascript client can't add custom headers? (as of what I've read in many places in SO) If this is true, this works with long-polling and webevents, but not with the Websocket transport.

Comment: @pomarc Did you ever confirm this? I've read something similar.

Comment: It works, but only for "long polling" connection type in SignalR. For using OAuth bearer authentication with WebSockets you should pass bearer token with query and implement custom `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` which will extract your token from query params. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531252/how-do-we-preform-owin-oauth-bearer-token-based-authentication-and-authorization

Comment: Worth noting that there is a minor security risk by using tokens in the query parameters like this since it will likely be logged on the server.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites - What pomarc said is true. I tested that. Go with the link that Bounz added.

Comment: This forces SignalR to use longPolling

Answer (score 14):

I'll post this for the the people that will have this issue in the future:

There are multiple approaches to this in order to just make it  work, but depending on the purpose of the application.

1. The first that I've seen makes `SignalR` work  with headers, which would seem very easy to implement:

   `$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: "Bearer " + token };`

The huge downside of this is that it forces `SignalR` to use `longPolling`, which you most definitely don't want, since you are using SignalR.

2. The second approach is to pass the `access token` that the client receives when logging in as a `query string`, right before connecting. Then, make a custom `Attribute` that inherits the `AuthorizeAttribute` ([follow this repo - not great in my opinion, but it makes a point](https://github.com/louislewis2/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/SignalRHelpers/QueryStringBearerAuthorizeAttribute.cs)).

Another approach with passing the token as `query string` is to [follow this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20615950/3084239) which creates an `OAuth Provider` and

> retrieves all other values from the token early in the pipeline

Again, this method is not the optimal  one since `query strings` are pretty vulnerable:

> query strings tend to be stored in web server logs (or exposed in
>   other ways even when using SSL). There is a risk of  someone
>   intercepting the tokens. You need to select an approach that fits your
>   scenario best.

3. The solution I am currently trying to implement (and will come back with updates once it works:D) is [based on this blog post](http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/05/authentication-with-signalr-and-oauth.html#.VebnnfmeDGc) which uses the `OAuth Bearer Token authentication` with `SignalR` by passing the token over a cookie into `SignalR` pipeline.

I believe this is the solution with the fewest compromises, but I will come back with more information once my implementation is complete.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

UPDATE
I managed to get WebApi token authentication to work with SignalR by storing the token in a cookie, then retrieve it in a provider.

You cah take a [look at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft-dx/aspnet-fundamentals/tree/master/AspNetFundamentals/aspnet04%20-%20SimpleTokenAuthentication) , but I mostly followed the article from above. Explicitly, here's what I did:

I created an `OAuthBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider` class that inherits from `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` and overridden the `RequestToken` method.

Now it looks for the cookie where the `BearerToken` is stored and retrieves its value. Then, it sets the `context.Token` to the value of the cookie.

Then, on the JavaScript part, you have to get the token (by authenticating using the user name and password) and store the token in a cookie.

```
public class OAuthBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        var tokenCookie = context.OwinContext.Request.Cookies["BearerToken"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCookie))
            context.Token = tokenCookie;

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

For a working sample, please take a look at the repo above.

Best of luck!

Comment: Have you had any luck / success with this?

Comment: In the end I had to abandon bearer token authentication and just go with cookie authentication. It is just the easier solution overall.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @overslacked I updated my answer and added working GitHub repo