# Validate our “Owin OAuth2 Bearer Token” from other Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I successfully authenticate and obtain a Token from my Owin TokenEnpoint (Katana implementation), but when i then call let's say.. my Java Api I would like to validate the issued Token.

So I would like to be able to call my Owin endpoint and just validate my Token, without authenticating again.

Facebook or Google provide something like:

https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={0}&access_token={1}
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sharing some info on how I solved this..

Just create a new endpoint in your Web.Api or you can even filter your context.Request.Path for your "/tokencheck/" path.

then you can finally:

```
context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
context.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = context.Ticket.Properties;
```

This question will help you develop a working solution:

[Get IPrincipal from OAuth Bearer Token in OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585872/get-iprincipal-from-oauth-bearer-token-in-owin)